# CompileC Yoga.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have been working on building a React native app and it's been working perfectly fine. A couple of days ago I got on an update for ios simulators and after the update all my installed apps were gone and all simulators were refreshed. When I try to build app on ios again I am getting this error.
The full error is as follows
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/muhammadaqeel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RICHLoad-grdecqvhxadocbfxxrsfifmleiew/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Yoga.o /Users/muhammadaqeel/Desktop/RICHLoad-main/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

My app is building perfectly fine on Android.
I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work in this case.
One of the solution I tried is

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
```

```
I am using 
"react-native": "0.64.2",
xcode version : Version 14.3
```

I am bulding my app using this command

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
```

Comment: Facing same issue... Found any solution? 2 weeks back it was working fine. Didn't change anything in the dependencies. May be xcode could be updated to the latest version.

Comment: @TheLuck yes, on this similar post someone provided the solution and it worked for me

Comment: Yeah! Later I found the same here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36758#issuecomment-1496210081

Created a patch version for react-native. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have faced the same issue after updating the Xcode to the latest version.

1. remove `pods` folder and `podfile.lock`
2. install pods `cd ios & pod install`
3. build project and you will get this error so for that apply step 4
4. You need to replace single | to || in yoga file.

Now, Build your project

Comment: This worked like charm ::
File path: node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp ::
Line: 30008 & Line: 2232 ::

Comment: You meant 3008, not 30008. btw. it didn't help anyways :)

Comment: Its working from me but it come back from time, is there a way to fix this ?