# error build: Could not build Objective-C module 'YogaKit'

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm adding Firebase to my react native project by following the documentation on https://rnfirebase.io/ and it has worked fine for android but not working for ios for me.

After adding all the required code in AppDelegate.mm and Podfile i'm getting this error while building the project from Xcode.

[image]

Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"


platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false


production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'MyApp' do
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  
  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end


  
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75949937/7846071 this one might be help you

Comment: @NensiKardani i dont see and single | in any of the yoga files. Could you please specify where i could find those

Comment: ok, There is a way to solve this issue.

Quit Xcode.
Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
Run pod install.
Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work for me either